# Rails 4 - Multiple Nested Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms, form-for

I trying to create a nested form with N models associated.

This is the schema:

[image: schema]

and I need a Edit-Form which iterate through all objects till the last one:

[image]

My **delivery object** looks like this:

```
class Delivery < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :boxes
```

and this is the **box object**

```
class Box < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :box, :polymorphic => true, :inverse_of => :box
    has_many :boxes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :boxes
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what was the result?

Comment: I tried this one: `= f.fields_for :boxes do |f|` and in this `f.fields_for :boxes do |ff|` but this code show me only the second level not the following...

Comment: you need to instantiate boxes

Comment: @Snake ok, tell me where and how to do this?

Comment: @larz in your DeliveriesController

Answer (score 0):

In the deliveries controller :

```
def new
  @delivery = Delivery.new
  # if you want 3 instantiated objects
  3.times { @delivery.boxes.build }
end
```